# cytoscape save graph as image by button

Tags: javascript, html, cytoscape.js, cytoscape

I saw in the [cytoscape.js](http://www.cytoscape.org/) tutorial that there are ways to represent the graph as image (png, jpg), but there is a way to represent it as regular graph, and if the user would want he can save it as image by click on button or similar option?

Didn't find simple way for that.

I am using python flask as my server side and cytoscape js for the graphes.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You don't need server side code to save files from the browser anymore.

You can save files using the `saveAs()` API in JS.  Here's a polyfill: https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/

If you want the graph data, it would just be

```
var jsonBlob = new Blob([ JSON.stringify( cy.json() ) ], { type: 'application/javascript;charset=utf-8' });

saveAs( jsonBlob, 'graph.json' );
```

Or for images

```
var b64key = 'base64,';
var b64 = cy.png().substring( content.indexOf(b64key) + b64key.length );
var imgBlob = base64ToBlob( b64, 'image/png' );

saveAs( imgBlob, 'graph.png' );
```

(Refer to other question re. [`base64toBlob()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16245767/creating-a-blob-from-a-base64-string-in-javascript))

Comment: Thank, its work with tiny change, i replace the scondeline with this: 'var b64 = cy.png().substring( cy.png().indexOf(b64key) + b64key.length );' i.e before this little change the **"content"** was not define and it throw error.

Comment: For more info, you can export as jpg, png, or json with numerous options: http://js.cytoscape.org/#core/export

Answer (score 3):

#### Improving the answer marked as correct:

You can use [`saveAs()`](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/) directly, simply do:

```
import { saveAs } from "file-saver"; //or require
...
saveAs(cy.png(), "graph.png");
```

No need to handle blob content, same goes for `.jpg()`

Comment: Thank you. This should be included in "marked as correct"

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/file-saver

Answer (score 0):

If you want a solution without further library usage, here an idea:

```
const pngBlob = await cy.png({
  output: 'blob-promise',
});

const fileName = 'myfile.png';
const downloadLink = document.createElement('a');
downloadLink.href = URL.createObjectURL(pngBlob);
downloadLink.download = fileName;
downloadLink.click();
```

Note that the `output` property of the `png()` function parameter can be used to directly generate a `Blob` object. If you use the value `blob-promise` the function returns a promise instead of a blog directly, so you can keep your UI non-blocking.

See the official [cytoscape docs](https://js.cytoscape.org/#cy.png) for more details.